# How can I download the same file from multiple URLs for increased speed?

Tags: linux, download, mirroring, download-manager, file-download

I'm working on a Linux machine (relatively recent distribution). I want to download a file which is mirrored at two different (HTTP) servers. Now, the file is large and the download speed from each location is low.

How can I download the file from both URLs, so as to use the combined bandwidth?

I don't mind if this requires some command-line work (as I doubt existing GUI apps support this).

Note: The file is not available via BitTorrent; that would obviously be a preferable solution if I could use it.

Comment: Why not just use Bittorrent to get the file instead?  Never used it, but look at https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/download-accelerator-for-linux-command-line-tools.html which purports to offer this functionality.

Comment: @davidgo: Because it's no available via BitTorrent.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/642061/46437

Comment: @AquariusPower: The accepted answer already says this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/)

man aria2c:

```
   -i, --input-file=<FILE>
          Downloads  the  URIs  listed  in  FILE. You can specify multiple
          sources for a single entity by putting multiple URIs on a single
          line  separated by the TAB character.  Additionally, options can
          be specified after each URI line. Option lines must  start  with
          one  or more white space characters (SPACE or TAB) and must only
          contain one option per line.  Input files can use gzip  compres‐
          sion.   When  FILE  is specified as -, aria2 will read the input
          from stdin.  See the Input File  subsection  for  details.   See
          also  the  --deferred-input option.  See also the --save-session
          option.
```

Comment: Also with `-s` and `-x` options.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Can you elaborate on that point?

Comment: I suspect this will work only if both servers support Content-range  in GET requests which is not always the case (especially with servers that throttle their download rate).

Comment: Note the `separated by the TAB character` when specifying multiple sources for the same file. With a space it doesn't work.